# Can you write selectors that reference other state slices in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to Redux/RTK so I'm still figuring things out.

**The situation:**

I have a locationsSlice which stores an array of ids (`favIds`) in the state.

I also have a forecastSlice which has an array of objects (`forecastObjects`).

**My question:**

I want to write a global selector that can return filtered forecast objects based on the ids in the locationsSlice. To do that, *I need to reference another slice's state*. What is the best way to do this?

I could write a hook for such logic, but is there a way to do this inside a slice? Is that bad practice?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to achieve this with RTK's built-in `createSelector` [documented here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector). Please let me know if this is an anti-pattern or anything.

```
// locationsSlice.js

import { createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// ...

const selectForecasts = (state) => state.locations.forecasts;
const favIds = (state) => state.user.favIds;

export const selectFavForecasts = createSelector(
  selectForecasts,
  favIds,
  (forecasts, ids) => {
    return forecasts.filter((forecast) => ids.includes(forecast.id));
  },
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it. Selectors are global in Redux, there is nothing preventing you from having a selector touch different slices. And it's very good to use `createSelector` when using `filter` as otherwise it will return a new reference every time which will create a lot of useless rerenders.

Comment: Understood, cheers for commenting